# func removeFilterPredicate(_ predicate: MPMediaPredicate) not working consistently

Tags: swift

I am experiencing an inconsistent issue when trying `func removeFilterPredicate(_ predicate: MPMediaPredicate)` however I **never** have an issue when trying `func addFilterPredicate(_ predicate: MPMediaPredicate)`

When I test my app and add the predicate it works every time without fail. When I try to remove the predicate usually it works, but sometimes it does not.

The behavior I expect is to remove the predicate and then a random song that does not match the previous predicate to play

What is actually sometimes happening is after I remove the predicate and skip to next song more songs from the previous predicate still play

I have found if I want to guarantee it to fail I can do so by adding the predicate to only play songs from a specific Artist and then rapidly skip a few songs and then try to remove the predicate.

The way I add the predicate is

```
func getSongsWithCurrentArtistFor(item: MPMediaItem) -> MPMediaQuery {
  let artistPredicate = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: item.artist, forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyArtist, comparisonType: .contains)
  let query = MPMediaQuery()
  query.addFilterPredicate(artistPredicate)
  return query
}


let lockArtist = MediaManager.shared.getSongsWithCurrentArtistFor(item: nowPlaying)
  if var items = lockArtist.items {
    items.shuffle()
    let descriptor = MPMusicPlayerMediaItemQueueDescriptor(itemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection(items: items))
    self.mediaPlayer.prepend(descriptor)
   }
```

Which again NEVER fails

To remove the predicate:

```
func removeArtistLockFor(item: MPMediaItem) -> MPMediaQuery {
  let artistPredicate = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: item.artist, forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyArtist)
  let query = MPMediaQuery()
  query.removeFilterPredicate(artistPredicate)
  return query
}

let unlockArtist = MediaManager.shared.removeArtistLockFor(item: nowPlaying)
  if var items = unlockArtist.items?.filter({ (item) -> Bool in
    return item.mediaType.rawValue <= MPMediaType.anyAudio.rawValue
      }) {
      items.shuffle()
       let descriptor = MPMusicPlayerMediaItemQueueDescriptor(itemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection(items: self.newSongs.shuffled()))
       self.mediaPlayer.prepend(descriptor)
 }
```

I am wondering if A) There is an issue with the way I am removing `MPMediaPropertyPredicate`, B) I need some sort of added method to fix the edge case of rapidly changing song, or C) both.

I know I have previously posted about issues with MPMediaPlayer .. specifically about`func prepend(_ descriptor: MPMusicPlayerQueueDescriptor)` but those issues were resolved in ios13. This is a new issue...and the fact that adding the predicate ALWAYS working makes me think this is more of a mistake on my part and not Apple's issue...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines in your **removeArtistLockFor** function

```
let query = MPMediaQuery()
  query.removeFilterPredicate(artistPredicate)
```

...appears to be creating a new instance of MPMediaQuery so unless it behaves like a singleton (which from the documentation doesn't appear to be the case), there will be nothing to remove at this point.

Should you be holding on to a reference to the query from when you add the predicate and pass it in to the remove function so you can then do

```
passedQuery.removeFilterPredicate(artistPredicate)
```